# Nameserver cant resolve my domain. My fault or theirs?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, dns-zone

On my dedicated server at server4you.de I had theese nameservers preconfigured:

```
nameserver      85.25.128.10
nameserver      85.25.255.10
```

they were unable to resolve my domain names 2xfun.de and 2x.to

i ran some dns check like here http://www.intodns.com/2xfun.de and everything looked fine.

after changing the nameserers to googles 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 everything resolved perfectly.

Is there anything wrong with my zones?

Comment: If you will do `dig` or `nslookup` on authoritative server you will see what is currently set and will be reproduced.

Comment: if i did it correctly it looks fine to me but i am not sure. could you check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I get with an nslookup of NS records on `2xfun.de`

```
Non-authoritative answer:
2xfun.de        nameserver = ns1.realm4hosting.com
2xfun.de        nameserver = ns2.realm4hosting.com

ns1.realm4hosting.com   internet address = 94.136.172.6
```

When I force those requests to go via `85.25.128.10` then I get

```
Server:  [85.25.128.10]
Address:  85.25.128.10

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to 85.25.128.10 timed-out
```

It's the same story for `85.25.255.10` so I would say it looks like your DNS service on your dedicated host is misconfigured in some way.

Comment: I have seen a provider configure a prebuilt machine with their own internal nameservers for resolving their own internal names.  It was up to me to find "real" recursive nameservers.

Answer (score 0):

If their nameservers can't lookup your domain but google's can then it looks like there is a problem with their name servers, but it's not always going to be their fault. How long ago was this domain setup? It may not have propagated yet.  Is this domain registered with them or do they think they are hosting it? Could their name servers have their own, incorrect, records form this domain.

Comment: i didnt change anything in the zones for weeks. the domains are also hosted completely elsewehere (inlcuding nameservers and registrar). nothing to do with them. if they had wrong records, i dont know where from they could have gotten them from...